# Android MP chart set date on x axis in format dd-MM-yyyy

Tags: android, charts

I am using MPCHART of android but want to show date value on the X-Axis but BarEntry takes on float value how to parse the date to enter the value in BarEntry or any alternative to add value to the bar chart of the x and y axis.

```
    private void grossChartSetup(ArrayList<BarEntry> grosssalesamountToday) {
    grossChart.setMarker(iMarker);

    grossChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    grossChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(24);
    grossChart.setPinchZoom(false);
    grossChart.setEnabled(false);
    grossChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    grossChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);
    grossChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    grossChart.setHighlightFullBarEnabled(false);
    grossChart.setOnChartGestureListener(this);


    BarDataSet orderDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(grosssalesamountToday, "Actual");
    orderDataSet1.setColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.darkCyan));
    BarData orderdata = new BarData(orderDataSet1);
    orderdata.setValueFormatter(new LargeValueFormatter());
    grossChart.setData(orderdata);

    float barWidth = 0.1f;
    grossChart.getBarData().setBarWidth(barWidth);

    XAxis orderXAxis = orderChart.getXAxis();
    orderXAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    orderXAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
```

//       orderXAxis.setValueFormatter(new DayXAxisFormatter());

```
    YAxis orderRightYAxis = orderChart.getAxisRight();
    YAxis orderLeftAxis = orderChart.getAxisLeft();
    orderLeftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    orderRightYAxis.setEnabled(false);

    grossChart.getLegend().setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.ABOVE_CHART_RIGHT);

    grossChart.invalidate();
    grossChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(7);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried converting Float to Int?

Comment: the value which is coming from a server is of date type i.e dd-mm-yyyy but bar entry only takes in the flaot format i want to pass the value to string format and show the date as it is on the x-axis

Comment: Is their any problem converting date to string?

Comment: its already in string i need to convert it in float and its creating a problem "22-10-2018" if u convert it in flaot what value it will give ? this is the issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own value formatter like below

```
public class MyYAxisValueFormatter implements IValueFormatter {


    public MyYAxisValueFormatter() {
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        // "value" represents the position of the label on the axis (x or y)
        // value => date in MiliSecond
        val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
        return dateFormat.format(value)
    }
}
```

and after that you can set this as your dataFormatter like below

```
dataSet.setValueFormatter(new MyYAxisValueFormatter())
```